# image Intervention error

Tags: php, image, laravel

I am trying to add a logo onto the navbar but the image I used was too big so I saw this package called intervention image that almost everyone talks about and decided to use it. But before using it I am not sure if it is properly installed. This is what happen:

Added this into the composer.json:

```
"require": {
//"laravel/framework": "5.1.*", < -- didn't use this since there is a 5.5.*
   "intervention/image": "dev-master"
},
```

run composer install

Added this inside config/app.php

Added inside the providers part:
Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class,

and added this inside the alias part:
'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class,

Run composer update and got this error:
[image]

I am not really sure if I should ignore it or not and continue using it but because I just started using image intervention, I don't want to messed up any installation since it might affect my code later on

While I am at it, I need to know if it is possible to resize the image in my navbar using imageIntervention in my app.blade.php in laravel.
Currently have something like this:

```
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                <img src="{{ URL::to('/image') }}/test.png">
            </ul>
```

Comment: did you research what "conflict with your requirements for minimum-stability" means?

Comment: Yup I did, they didn't really explain much but  just say to add something inside the composer.json. But those things are already inside. But don't know for some reason everything working again

Comment: then you need to read more about what 'minimum-stability' is for ... actually read the information not just Stack Overflow questions, the actual documentation for composer of what that feature is for ... always go to the actual source ... you are stopping yourself from getting to answers  ...   you are so close to being able to answer your questions yourself  :-D

Comment: Noted, will do that from now on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install intervention, run command

```
composer require intervention/image
```

[Intervention Docs](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation)

Comment: he no need .. he added it to composer.json he just need run "composer update"

Comment: I did the composer update and it return me that error as shown in my question's screenshot

Comment: Delet whot you gived manualy and then run command ( i never saw version devmaster ) all my packages i m using have numbers in it

Comment: I just realized the composer require intervention/image  suddenly works, I just tried remove everything and redo it again and have no idea what just happen